# object detection in iphone using openCV? template matching or haar?

Tags: objective-c, opencv

I need to do an iphone app that can look for a image pattern in an image. (sth like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLKLg2AnvGE))

After numerous google searching, i feel that the only option i have in to use template matching function in the opencv which has been ported for objectiveC.

I found an excellent starting point for a simple opencv project in objectiveC from [this](https://github.com/niw/iphone_opencv_test) github code.

But it is only using edge detection and face detection features in the openCV. I need an objectiveC example that uses the template matching function - "cvMatchTemplate" - in objectiveC for iPhone?

Below is the code I have at this moment: (at least it is not giving me error, but this piece of code, return a completely black image, i am expecting a result image where matched area will be brighter?)

```
    IplImage *imgTemplate = [self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"laughing_man.png"]];
    IplImage *imgSource = [self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:imageView.image];        
    CvSize sizeTemplate = cvGetSize(imgTemplate);
    CvSize sizeSrc = cvGetSize(imgSource);       
    CvSize sizeResult = cvSize(sizeSrc.width - sizeTemplate.width+1, sizeSrc.height-sizeTemplate.height + 1);
    IplImage *imgResult = cvCreateImage(sizeResult, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
    cvMatchTemplate(imgSource, imgTemplate, imgResult, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
    cvReleaseImage(&imgSource);
    cvReleaseImage(&imgTemplate);        
    imageView.image = [self UIImageFromIplImage:imgResult];
    cvReleaseImage(&imgResult);
```

p/s: Or, should I try to recognize object using cvHaarDetectObjects?

Comment: hi can you help me in one task

Comment: hi sorry i have stopped working on this for too long...

Comment: so your task was completed or not?

Comment: hi based on the comment from another user below, he pointed to me that template matching is not the right direction for my purpose. and he suggested me using SIFT or SURF.

Comment: hi my task is to capture human image and make its midget (shorter in size) image... suggest me best practices ..plz

Comment: hi, just random thoughts in my mind. have u explored the native human face recognition in iOS 5.0? i never tried but it should be able to tell you the coordinates of the human face in your picture. then u can stretch the lower part of the face probably.

Comment: i am doing this face recognition but i need to recognize completed body so i can crop this body then make it smaller....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25666/discussion-between-rajneesh071-and-dunforget)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result from cvMatchTemplate is a 32-bit floating point image.  In order to display the result, you'll need to convert that to an unsigned char, 8-bit image (IPL_DEPTH_8U).

The CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED method produces values between [0, 1] and cvConvertScale provides an easy way to do the scaling and type conversion.  Try adding the following to your code:

```
IplImage* displayImgResult = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize( imgResult ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);    
cvConvertScale( imgResult, displayImgResult, 255, 0 );
imageView.image = [self UIImageFromIplImage:displayImgResult];
```

Comment: Hi jeff, thanks for ur answer I will try it out tr when I get back to work. Meanwhile can I ask u also, to achieve something similar to the YouTube link I posted, should I stick to matchtemplate or should I look into cvHaarDetectObject?

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for your pointer! I finally manage to see some meaningful patterns returned by opencv (you can see them here:http://encryptedpixel.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/346/). I have created another question to know how to analyze those patterns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673684/how-to-analyze-results-returned-by-opencvs-cvmatchtemplate If you have the answer, do help me thanks!

Comment: Just had a change to look at that video and I'd recommend a different approach.  I think you'll get much better results using an object recognition type approach using SIFT or SURF features.  These will give you some robustness to scale, rotation and are much more discriminative than template matching.