# how to analyze min max loc returned by opencv's cvMatchTemplate?

Tags: objective-c, opencv

I am trying to detect objects in image on an iphone app.

I am using the cvMatchTemplate function, I manage to see some patterns returned by the cvMatchTemplate function (I chose CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED).

Positive Results (result image is 163x371):

http://encryptedpixel.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/photo-13-7-11-11-52-19-am.jpeg

cvMinMaxLoc returns: min (102,244) max(11,210)
The min point is making some sense here, the position of the dark spot is really 102,244 in the result image of 163x371

Negative Results:

[image]

cvMinMaxLoc returns: min (114,370) max(0,0)
This is not making sense, there is totally no results, why is there still a min point at 114,370?

I need to know how to analyze these results programatically so that I can say "Hey I found the object!" in objectiveC for iPhone app?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, it means that template matching is not the algorithm you are searching for, actually, OpenCV gives you a good result, the problem is the difference between a good result and a relevant one. Here the result is correct but not relevant... Maybe you should try to recognize features instead of finding templates who match...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cvMinMaxLoc will always return the position of the minimum and maximum values of their input. It only "doesn't make sense" in your particular application. You should check the *value* at the returned position for the minimum and do something like threshold it to see if that's a probable match for your template. A template match will yield a very low or a very high value, depending on the method you chose.